# How to catch TypeInitializationException?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How can I catch this `TypeInitializationException`? Don't really care if it is C# or VB.NET code. Here is some sample code of what I am trying to figure out (this is not real code - just something to show what I am dealing with):

```
Public Class Test 
    Public Shared testObj as Object = CreateObj()

    Public Shared Function CreateObj() as Object
         throw new Exception("Ha!")
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub Main()
       Dim i as Integer = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Suppose I have no control over `CreateObj` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB you have a couple of options depending on what type of application it is.

If the Application is a console app or windows form app then you can extend the My class with an UnhandledException event.

```
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
           'Handle error here
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

If it's an ASP.Net web app then add some code to the Global.asax file (events below truncated for brevity).

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when an error occurs
    End Sub

    Private Sub Global_asax_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Error
        'Catches all errors
    End Sub
End Class
```

As a rule you shouldn't call a method from a type initializer.  Use the class initializer to set the initial value in your Sub Main.

Comment: What if this is in a windows form?

Comment: Sorry, the top example is console & windows forms.  I fixed the post.  Just add a class file to your project and put the top example into the file and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Try/Catch` block, as for any other exception... If `Main` is the program entry point, you're out of luck, because the exception might be thrown before you have a chance to catch it. I say "might" because I'm not sure about the rules regarding type initialization in VB; if they're the same as in C# 4, the code you posted will run fine, because the type initializer won't be executed until it's actually necessary, and in your code it's never necessary (because `testObj` is never used)

Comment: "and in your code it's never necessary" - the Shared (static in C#) testObj field will be initialized, and therefore CreateObj will be called, before the Main method is executed.  So it is necessary.

Comment: I wrote the equivalent code in C#4, and CreateObject wasn't called, unless the Main method accessed a static field. But the rules might be different in VB...